# How to launch COM server in separate dllhost process?

Tags: windows, com, dllhost

My COM component implemented as surrogated dll. I create one by calling CoCreateInstanceEx(), but it started in shared dllhost.exe process. Is there a way to launch my COM component in separate dllhost process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surrogate sharing is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Sharing only happens if the AppId matches.  Give yours a unique one.